# How many unique sums $x_0+x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_n=S$ where $x_i>x_{i-1}$?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, summation, algorithms, computer-science

How many unique sums $x_0+x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_n=S$ where $x_i>x_{i-1}$ are there for each $S$?

$x_i$ and $S$ are non-negative integers.

My Computer Science prof also said that this can be solved with a recursive algorithm, how is this done?

Comment: What do you mean by "unique sum"? What's the difference with a "sum"?

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, you are trying to count the number of partitions of $S$ into distinct parts. If so, see here for more information: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)

Comment: Should the $x_i$ be integers? Natural numbers? Real numbers? (That would make the counting easy.)

Comment: @carmichael561 yes! that is correct

Comment: Do you want only $x_n > x_{n-1}$ or do you want $x_n > x_{n-1} > \dots > x_2 > x_1$?

Comment: @Crostul the latter

Comment: @Arthur non-negative integers. thank you for the correction

Comment: Take a look at the recurrence that is formula $(59)$ [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PartitionFunctionP.html); it also appears [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)#Restricted_part_size_or_number_of_parts).

Comment: Note that if $x_0 = 0$ then we have a partition into exactly $n$ unequal parts, while if $x_0 \gt 0$ then we have exactly $n+1$ unequal parts.

Answer (score 3):

To reformulate, you are asking for the number of partitions of $S$ with distinct parts. There is a generating series for this. Let $q(s)$ be the number you are counting, then
$$Q(x)=\sum_nq(n)x^n=\prod_{i=1}^\infty(1+x^i)$$
For a fixed $S$, you can just compute the coefficient of $x^S$ in the product
$$Q_S(x)=(1+x)(1+x^2)(1+x^3)\cdots(1+x^S).$$
For example, for $S=4$, the coefficient of $x^4$ in
$$(1+x)(1+x^2)(1+x^3)(1+x^4)$$
is 2, so there are two such sums. For $S=5$, the coefficient of $x^5$ in
$$(1+x)(1+x^2)(1+x^3)(1+x^4)(1+x^5)$$
is 3.

These [notes](https://math.berkeley.edu/~mhaiman/math172-spring10/partitions.pdf) are useful.

Comment: Thank you for the informed answer! However I think there is circular reasoning here. The coefficient of $x^s$ is exactly what I'm trying to find - the number of combinations of sums that add up to S. I hope I'm explaining this clearly.

Comment: @JackBlack: No circular reasoning is to be found here.  Rather you asked about computing a count of partitions with distinct parts (not in some many words) without advising Readers what your true objective was.

Answer (score 1):

If $Q(m,k)$ denotes the number of distinct $k$ partitions of $m$ and $P(m,k)$ denotes the number of $k$ partitions (not necessarily distinct) of $m$, then we have the recurrence relation
\begin{align*}
P(m,k) = P(m-1, k-1) + P(m-k, k)
\end{align*}
and 
\begin{align*}
Q(m,k) = P\left(m - \frac{1}{2}k(k-1), k\right)
\end{align*}
What we need is $Q(S, n)$ and can be calculated recursively. For example,
\begin{align*}
Q(17,4) &= P(11,4) \\
 &= P(10,3) + P(7,4) \\
&=P(9,2) + P(7,3) + P(6,3) + P(3,4) \\
&= 4 + P(6,2) + P(4,3) + P(5,2) + P(3,3) \\
&= 4 + 3 + 1 + 2 + 1 \\
&= 11
\end{align*}